# mvn missing curator framework

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have the following mvn config file, when I try to do mvn package, it gets

Failed to execute goal on project regulation-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project regulation-service:regulation-service:jar:1.0: Failure to find com.netflix.curator:curator:jar:1.1.3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

the curator jar is in the local repository, any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>regulation-service</groupId>
    <artifactId>regulation-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>regulation-service</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.elasticride.regulation.RegulationServer</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>


        ....  
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you define a dependency in maven if you don't explicitly define a `type` then maven presumes the artifact is `jar`.

You have the following dependency defined:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.curator</groupId>
    <artifactId>curator</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So maven is trying to find a jar artifact in the repository for the given groupId, artifactId and version. However searching in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.netflix.curator), shows that there is only a `pom` file available.

You either need to change the dependency to be:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.curator</groupId>
    <artifactId>curator</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Or remove the dependency completely.